# How to store and get back stemmed text in solr?

Tags: solr, stemming

Usually we store the original text and index the stemmed text and or the original text in Solr.

Is there a possibility to store the stemmed content in solr? 
Because my goal is to obtain the stemmed version of the text when I do a query to solr.

Thanks in advance,

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

why not just store the field you have the stemmer defined? refer to the wiki page(s), for instance: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options

Comment: sorry to answer just now! In fact, related to my tries and my understanding the stored text is every time the original text and not stemmed one. Only the index are stemmed. Is it right?